# get position of label from main view

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, position, subview

i have a UILabel (name : lbl)  and a UIView ,  except main view (name : myView)
i added my label to myView as subview

now ! i want to get  the position of the label in main view ! not in myView

this is my project :

http://www.mediafire.com/?w63bnurf28n8cnb

i dont want to use this code :

```
CGPoint pos;
pos.x=myView.frame.origin.x+lbl.frame.origin.x  ;
pos.y= myView.frame.origin.y+lbl.frame.origin.y ;
```

because if i want to rotate the myView using  CGAffineTransformMakeRotation  this code does not work !

i want position of the label in main view !!

Comment: you can get the position of your label in your myView and then get the position of myView in your main view and then add them together..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UIView` has methods build in for converting points up and down the view hierarchy :) Either of these should do the trick.

```
    [mainView convertPoint:lbl.center fromView:myView];
    [myView convertPoint:lbl.center toView:mainView];
```